# Populate a anchor tag with OnClientClick/ OnServerClick from C# backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

I have a dynamic data that has to be populated on UI from .cs file.
Currently I am doing it this way:

**File.aspx**

```
<div id="divLinks" class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%;" runat="server">
</div>
```

**File.aspx.cs**

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("<a target=\"_blank\"><img class=\"mySlides\" src=\"" + imageLink + "\" style=\"width:100%; height:350px;\" runat=\"server\" onServerClick=\"MyFuncion_Click("+link+")\" ></a>");
divLinks.InnerHtml = str.ToString();

protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do something when clicked a link with parameter from that link as identifier
}
```

After doing this, I am not able to reach LinkButton_Click function from onServerClick.

Can someone help me with this siince I want a link with unique value to be passed to function for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add aspnet Controls to the page as a string. That is not gonna Work. You need to add "real" Controls to the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //do not add dynamic controls here
    }

    //create a new ImageButton instance on every page load
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton();

    //set some properties
    ib.CssClass = "mySlides";
    ib.ImageUrl = "~/myImage.png";

    //add the click method
    ib.Click += LinkButton_Click;

    //add the button to an existing control
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ib);
}
```

Note that you need to add dynamic controls on every Page Load, and that includes a PostBack.